How to Overlap Contours to Detect Columns in a Table Using OpenCV and PyTorch?"
I am working on a project to detect tables and extract columns from images using a deep learning model with PyTorch and OpenCV. While I can successfully detect the tables and obtain contours for the individual cells, I am struggling with accurately defining the column boundaries. While I have my proper column mask. I need to use it alongside the table mask to get the ocr to maintain the structure of the table.
Here’s a summary of my approach:

Preprocessing: Resize and normalize the image.
Model Inference: Use a custom PyTorch model to generate table and column masks.
Contour Detection: Detect contours in the table mask using cv2.findContours.
Filtering Contours: Filter out small or irrelevant contours based on area.
Bounding Rectangles: Draw bounding boxes around the detected contours.

I want to improve the column detection by considering the spatial relationships between the contours. Specifically, I want to overlap the contours to determine the column boundaries. If two contours overlap significantly along the x-axis, they should be considered part of the same column.
What I’ve Tried:

Sorting contours based on their x-coordinates.

Filtering contours based on area to remove noise.

Using bounding boxes to visualize detected tables.


Issues:

Difficulty in determining accurate column boundaries.

Contours often represent individual cells, making it hard to group them into columns.


Code:
Here's the relevant part of my code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from PIL import Image
from albumentations import Compose, Normalize
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2

# Model Definition (DenseNet and TableNet classes omitted for brevity)

TRANSFORM = Compose([
    Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225], max_pixel_value=255),
    ToTensorV2()
])

def perform_ocr(image):
    # Perform OCR using Tesseract
    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')

def predict(img_path):
    orig_image = Image.open(img_path).resize((1024, 1024))
    test_img = np.array(orig_image.convert('LA').convert("RGB"))
    image = TRANSFORM(image=test_img)["image"]

    with torch.no_grad():
        image = image.unsqueeze(0)
        table_out, column_out = model(image)
        table_out = torch.sigmoid(table_out).detach().numpy().squeeze(0).transpose(1, 2, 0) > 0.5
        column_out = torch.sigmoid(column_out).detach().numpy().squeeze(0).transpose(1, 2, 0) > 0.5

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(table_out.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    contours = [c for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) > 3000]

    # Visualization and OCR steps omitted for brevity

    for c in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(orig_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 4)

    # How to overlap contours to determine columns?
    # ...

    cv2.imshow("Detected Tables", orig_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# Load model and process image (model loading code omitted for brevity)


Questions:

How can I overlap the detected contours to accurately determine the column boundaries?

What is the best approach to handle overlapping contours in OpenCV for column detection?

Are there any recommended techniques or best practices to improve the accuracy of column detection in tables?


Any guidance or suggestions on how to effectively overlap contours to detect columns would be greatly appreciated! A newbie in image processing so you can be a little direct on your answer please !
Note this project involves "scanned documents", if that is important.
EDIT: I have to tell the reason for the above requirement
vanilla OCR misplaces the ordering of the columns in the table a lot , I'm trying to use column masks to maintain the correct structure

we can't see why you are having difficulties with detecting the columns -> reproducible example is needed for such problems.

oh sorry , im not sure i can post something for a reproducable example but i tried to write my requirement . Looking out for nothing more than advices . Thanks for replying

something similar can help your cause

picture please. some sample picture. the data, not a screenshot. must be representative of your true problem, not a sketch/illustration/"something like that" that isn't similar in relevant aspects

related question, same user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78338551/how-to-conserve-the-structure-during-ocr

@ChristophRackwitz yeah  i tried to get column mask inbetween these two question and was trying to conserve the structure . Thanks a lot for your suggestion there . I will try it out

@user18025483 if you have a very clean detection and very clean data, loop through the contours and append (X,Y) coordinates. Check the most occuring X and Y values since these will corresponds to vertical and horizontal lines. But again, no idea if this will work.

@ChristophRackwitz  I wasn't able to upload a sample image of because of the restriction on image size but the images i have trained the model on are  scanned images of research papers

@TinoD My detection part is very good. Images may not be that great but both the table mask and column mask are very accurate, I just want a way to make sure columns are grouped as a table correctly. NOTE: There can be multiple tables and that's where my problem arises. Thank you for your time

I'll post this as a possible solution to your problem, knowing that I cannot help solve your problem because I cannot see your images. As I said just check X and Y coordinates of the contours and do some statistics. I would normally go with column-wise/row-wise sums and check for peaks but this will fail with a lot of tables in the same image. So, I decided to go contour by contour.
Alas the gibberish table:

Code is:

detect contours
get X, Y
get count of values in X, Y (recurring values means cell borders)
threshold
plot unique values

Here's the code:
im = cv2.imread("FakeTable.png") # read im
imGray = cv2.imread("FakeTable.png", 0) # and as gray
imOTSU = cv2.threshold(imGray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1] # get otsu with cell as positive
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imOTSU, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # find contours
plt.figure() # figure
plt.imshow(im) # show image
for c in contours: # for every contour
    if cv2.contourArea(c)>1000: # filter out letters
        X, Y = c.T # get coords
        counts = np.bincount(X[0]) # get bin counts of values in X
        for uniqueX in np.where(counts > 10)[0]: # threshold, you can think about another approach, this is not optimal
            plt.axvline(uniqueX, color = "b") # plot
        # see X for explanation
        counts = np.bincount(Y[0])
        for uniqueY in np.where(counts > 50)[0]:
            plt.axhline(uniqueY, color = "r")
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()

And the results:


Two tables next to each other with different sizes:


Again, I cannot come up with a better solution since I don't know how your data looks like. Hope this helps.
